# Joomla and MYSQL DATABASE update time

Tags: mysql, joomla

Hi am using joomla and a mysql database hosted by daily razor on a site I had programmed by external contractors. 
I am testing the site and find when I change parameters on the database in phpadmin that the site does not update this info, for a period of time.
Is their away to manually update the website with the new database information.
Thanks
Andy

Comment: Change what parameters? Why are you changing any parameters through phpmyadmin?

Answer (score 1):

As you've already said that you've disabled the Joomla cache plugins and it appears you're seeing the results of a cache mechanism you will have to look to the other possible areas.

If you're using a commercial Joomla template, then some of the template frameworks have built-in cache mechanism. These often can be enabled even if you have turned off the Joomla cache systems.

The other place could be your hosting provider, you'll have to ask them if there is a caching system on your plan.

As you talking about database changes, the last area probably doesn't apply but if you're using a CDN (like Cloudfront et. al) you can invalidate items on the CDN (images, CSS other public files) via the CDN's control panel usually to speed up the visibility of the new files.

Finally, why are you changing parameters via PHPMyAdmin? This seems odd to me…

Comment: Hi CPPLThanks for this, I will look in to.  The hosting service has spent 12 hours looking in to this and they may be the cause, they don't know yet.  The reason I use phpmyadmin to import database updates, it is far easier and quicker to do via a spreadsheet first, the import has worked before with great success and saved lots of time,.  This is a new site and what I am doing is a learning curve and the parameters of the site is a lot to populate, even testing 6 custom categories requires 700rows of parameters. Thanks Andy

Comment: I hope you get it sorted out, if not, try asking on [the Joomla Q&A StackExhange site](http://joomla.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 0):

You might need to disable the cache plugin (at your admin backend) and the system cache (under global config). This should help. You should do this while at development time, when you want your changes to be reflected right away. Otherwise disabling the cache plugin would make the site load much slower.